# Realm in SwiftUI: Index out of bounds error after delete when using @ObservedSectionedResults

Tags: arrays, swift, realm

When I add multiple notes and try to swipe to delete them, the app crashes and displays this error message:

> Thread 1: "Index 3 is out of bounds (must be less than 3)."

```swift
import SwiftUI
import RealmSwift

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedSectionedResults(Memo.self, sectionKeyPath: \.firstLetter) var sectionedMemo
    
    @State var contentText = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                ForEach(sectionedMemo) { section in
                    Section {
                        ForEach(section) { memo in
                            Text(memo.content)
                                .swipeActions(edge: .trailing) {
                                    Button{
                                        let realm = try! Realm()
                                        try! realm.write {
                                            realm.delete(memo)
                                        }
                                    } label: {
                                        Image(systemName: "trash")
                                            .tint(.red)
                                    }
                                }
                        }
                    } header: {
                        Text(section.key)
                    }
                }
            }
            TextField("Enter the contents of the memo", text: $contentText)
                .frame(width: 200)
            
            Button("Add memo") {
                let newMemo = Memo()
                newMemo.content = contentText
                
                let realm = try! Realm()
                try! realm.write {
                    realm.add(newMemo)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have looked into this error but have not found any promising information.
However, I found a similar problem on realm-swift's GitHub, so I'm posting it here:
[Index out of bounds error after delete when using @ObservedSectionedResults](https://github.com/realm/realm-swift/issues/8294)
I couldn't find a solution even after looking at this ...

Comment: ObservedSectionedResults Comes built in with a delete function that connects with SwiftUI there is no reason to recreate.

Comment: I think you found "promising information", I would read it like: It is a bug and a fix is made, but not yet released.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! It has been modified to allow removal using the 'remove()' method with a '$' like @ObservedResults, but it has not been released and is not usable. Does that mean?

Comment: @loremipsum It would be great if you could post an answer utilizing that function as the documentation is pretty light in that area and the implementation is a tad unclear. I think that would answer the OP's question.